# /proc/user_beancounter how to perform monitoring

Tags: linux, monitoring, openvz

I want to perform monitoring of /proc/user_beancounters to see when the system hits the limits and **what process** is to blame.

Does anybody know tools for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Nagios for monitoring this file. It is not supported out-of-the-box, but [this](http://github.com/peletiah/openvz) plugin adds support for `/proc/user_beancounters`.

If Nagios is too much bloat for you, you might want to take a look at these Ruby scripts which sporadically check the file for any changes and in the case the values increase, they send an e-mail: [1](http://cjohansen.no/content/download/1788/14363/version/4/file/ubc_monitor), [2](https://svn.alkaloid.net/gpl/codelets/checkubc/checkubc.rb)

If you only want to have the values presented in a human-readable format, you can try the shell scripts provided [here](http://wiki.vpslink.com/Memory_Utilization_Script).

Comment: thanks. but for my vps it will be too big overhead, I mean installing nagios. I looking at munin now.

Comment: Maybe Cacti is also a choice. Here a script that parses the /proc/user_beancounters: http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cacti-templates/issues/detail?id=95